# Vertical Centering a block <a> in IE7

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7, internet-explorer-6

I'm trying to get vertical centering a block  in IE7 (IE6 if possible too), let me get one thing clear - I'm not vertically centering the actual element, but the text within the element. This is my CSS and HTML which works on IE8 and above, but not below.

```
a {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 100px;
    height: 54px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

<a href="#">Hello superlongword</a>
```

Now I know IE6 is virtually dead, I'd still like to support it if possible but if not then IE7 is fine. I want to try keep it with a single element as much as possible - it's for a navigator, so I don't want elements upon elements just for one link.

**EDIT**

I've decided to go with sprites, it'll be much easier for a navigator - not the best solution, but I'll be happy with the outcome. If any posted solutions do work, I'll swap over to them. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `display:inline-block` with a placeholder element to vertically center the block hyperlink:

```html
    <style type="text/css">
    #blockbox { width: 500px; height: 500px; border: 1px solid black;}
    #container, #placeholder { height: 100%; }
 
    #content, #placeholder { display:inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
    </style>
    <div id="blockbox">
      <div id="container">
        <a id="content">
        Vertically centered content in a block box of fixed dimensions
        </a>
        <span id="placeholder"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

**References**

- [CSS Vertical Centering](http://www.brunildo.org/test/vertmiddle.html)
- [IE7-/Win img, vertical-align middle](http://www.brunildo.org/test/IEWvmodd.php)

Answer (score 1):

If you know it will be just one line of text, use line-height.

It is far from a single element, but you could just use an actual table cell. It's ugly, but supporting IE6 is an ugly affair.

```
table {
    border: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    height: 54px;
    width: 100px;
}
td {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
a {
    background: black;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

<table><tr><td><a href="#">Hello superlongword</a></td></td></table>
```

If you know the link will be a certain number of lines, you can center using one extra element and a margin. (e.g. `<a><em>anchor text</em></a>`, `em { margin-top:12px }`)

If you don't know the height of the element to be centered, you need table-cell layout behavior. The only way to get this in IE6 is with an actual table cell or JavaScript. Sorry.

Comment: Nope, which is why there is a "superlongword", it's designed to be multi-lined otherwise I would of used line-height.

Comment: Yeah a very ugly solution indeed. I'm not so fussed about IE6, a display: block; does most of it but IE7 is a must.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug. The way to fix this, which may not be applicable in your situation, is to add a Float to the element and have it display as inline-block to make hasLayout work in IE. I will also supply FF2 hacks to get around issues there too.

Fixed code:

```
a { 
    display: inline-block;
    display: -moz-inline-stack; /*FF2 Hack*/
    zoom: 1; /*IE inline-block star hack*/
    *display: inline; /*IE inline-block star hack*/
    float: left; 
    width: 100px;
    _height: 54px; /*FF2 Hack*/
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center; 
    text-decoration: none; 
    margin: 0px auto;
}

<a href="#">Hello superlongword</a>
```

### EDIT

I didn't add a float, because I figured with the other hacks being used, it wouldn't matter.

Comment: It's lacking the 54px height, and when added ... it doesn't work in the latest browsers either... look: http://jsfiddle.net/KqraT/5/

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try a padding?

```
a {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 20px;
    background: black;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
}

<a>Hello superlongword</a>
```

That sure works crossbrowser atleast for IE7 (couldn't test on IE6), [example](http://jsfiddle.net/a4XHa/)